# Deleting Bank Accounts from an Item in Plaid API

Tags: plaid

My API is able to link a client's bank account, but is unable to 'unlink' it.  The documentation specifies that 3 body params are needed: "client_id", "secret", & "access_token."  However, from what I have read an access_token can be linked to MANY accounts.  Is there a way to retrieve the access_token associated with a client's client_id & account_ID, and subsequently remove that account while not removing others (if they exist)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: No.

There is currently no way for you as a developer to delete, say, the user's checking account from an Item/access token while keeping access to e.g. the user's savings account at the same bank behind the same login.

That said, I'd be interested in hearing more about your use case -- it's possible that the "Select Account" feature might solve the problem you are looking for, and we're also rolling out some improvements to Select Account soon that might make it work even better for you.